# Android: Unable to sync an old project, Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve error

Tags: android, gradle

I tried to open an old project, which is not mine, but it's not able to sync and build properly with the errors of `Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5. Show Details Affected Modules: app`
the error is shown for almost each dependency, [image: here is a screen]
i tried invalidating caches and restarting, cleaning the project and adding google to reporsitories.

here is my project gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }

    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter{ url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

here is the app module gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.safesoft.inv.hyper"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 14
    versionName "1.0.10"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true //important

    ndk
            {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"
    }

}

buildTypes {
    release {

        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError false

}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'

}




}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5@aar') {
    // exclusion is not necessary, but generally a good idea.
    exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
}
implementation 'com.haozhang.libary:android-slanted-textview:1.2'
implementation 'com.haozhang.libary:android-slanted-textview:1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.uniquestudio:checkbox:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.labo.kaji:swipeawaydialog:0.1.0'
implementation 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.emmasuzuki:easyform:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.github.paolorotolo:expandableheightlistview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.victor:lib:1.0.4'
implementation 'eu.inloop:simplerecycleradapter:0.3.1'
implementation 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
implementation 'com.jzxiang.pickerview:TimePickerDialog:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
implementation 'com.dropbox.core:dropbox-core-sdk:3.0.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'
implementation 'pl.coreorb:selection-dialogs:0.9.1'
//Button
implementation 'com.rilixtech:materialfancybuttons:1.8.7'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.6.0'
implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:core:1.9.8'
implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.9.8'
//implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'
//Icons
implementation 'com.rilixtech:entypo-typeface:1.0.0.3'
implementation 'co.lemonlabs:expandable-button-menu:1.0.0'
//Date time pickr
implementation 'com.github.florent37:singledateandtimepicker:1.2.2'
// externel librery
implementation project(':folding-cell')
implementation project(':lib_badge')
implementation project(':library_bth')
implementation project(':materialbarcodescanner')
implementation project(path: ':SpinKitLib')
implementation project(':sweet_alert_dialog_library')
// /Libs
implementation files('libs/Jaybird2_2_4.jar')
implementation files('libs/telpo_api.jar')
implementation files('libs/core-3.1.0.jar')
implementation files('libs/opencsv-3.9.jar')
implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.0.3.jar')
implementation files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3.jar')
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

implementation files('libs/commons-net-1.4.1.jar')
}
```

Here is the project's hierarchy:

[image]

i should mention that this is a new job, and this project was made by the old developer 4 years ago, and i have to change some things inside the app (changing listViews with recyclerViews for example).